# how to send Secure data to Client using SSL 

Tags: php, session, ssl, https

I am creating a login system for which i need to send data securely.

I want to send PHP Session Data using  SSL

But i didn't know how to send data over Https://

Please Guide Me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check: [How can I force users to access my page over HTTPS instead of HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85816/1166880) for details on assuring that your page is served via https.

Answer (score 1):

> i didn't know how to send data over Https://

Exactly the same way as over HTTP.

But you should also set the HTTP only and secure flags on the session cookie.

Comment: ... and make sure the links also point to `https://...`, as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8964190/372643 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8765067/372643