# Force HTTPS for specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

This should be a quick one... here is my current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What I need to do is make sure that if `http://www.mydomain.com/cart/` is reached, it needs to force HTTPS ... so `/cart/` and anything within `/cart/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the request has been sent to `http://www.mydomain.com/cart/`, if there is any sensitive data in the request, it's too late. Force it to break! At least, it will give you an indication that there's something wrong with your links. More details in previous answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8765067/372643
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964190/372643

> [ ... ] by the time the request reaches the server,
>   it's too late. If there is a MITM, he has done his attack (or part of
>   it) before you got the request.
>
> The best you can do by then is to reply without any useful content. In
>   this case, a redirection (using 301 or 302 and the Location header)
>   could be appropriate. However, it may hide problems if the user (or
>   even you as a developer) ignores the warnings (in this case, the
>   browser will follow the redirection and retry the request almost
>   transparently).
>
> Therefore, I would simply suggest returning a 404 status:
>
> - `http://yoursite/` and `https://yoursite/` are effectively two distinct sites. There is no reason to expect a 1:1 mapping of all
>     resources from the URI spaces from one to the other (just in the same
>     way as you could have a completely different hierarchy for
>     `ftp://yoursite/`).
> - More importantly, this is a problem that should be treated upstream: the link that led your user to this resource using `http://`
>     should be considered as broken. Don't make it work automatically.
>     Having a 404 status for a resource that shouldn't be there is fine. In
>     addition, returning an error message when there is an error is good:
>     it will force you (or at least remind you) as a developer that you
>     need to fix the page/form/link that led to this problem.

---

**EDIT:** (Example)

Let's say you have `http://example.com/`, the non-secure section of your site that allows the user to browse items. They're not logged in at that stage, so it's fine to do it over plain HTTP.

Now, it's cart/payment time. You want HTTPS. You send the user to `https://example.com/cart/`. If one of the links that sends the user to the cart part is using plain HTTP (i.e. `http://example.com/cart/`), it's a development mistake. It just shouldn't be there. Making the process break when you thought you were going to be sent to `https://example.com/cart/` allows the developer to see it (and, once fixed, the user should never have the problem).

If it's just about the point to the HTTPS section of your site (typically, an HTTP GET via a link somewhere), it's not necessarily that big a risk.

Where automatic redirects become even more dangerous is when they hide bigger problems.

For example, you're on `https://example.com/cart/creditcarddetails` and you've filled in some information that should really just stay over SSL. However, the developer has made a mistake and a plain `http://` link is used in the form. In addition, the developer (a user/human after all) has clicked on "don't show me this message again" in Firefox when it says "Warning: you're going from a secure page to a non-secure page" (by the way, unfortunately, Firefox warns a posteriori: it has already made the insecure request by the time it shows the user that message). Now, that GET/POST request with sensitive data is sent first to that incorrect plain `http://` link and the automatic rewrites tells the browser to try the request again over `https://`. It looks fine because, as far as the user is concerned, this all happened in a fraction of a second. However, it's not: sensitive data was sent in clear.

Making the plain HTTP section of what should only be over HTTPS not do anything useful actually helps you see what's wrong more clearly. Since the users should never end up there anyway if the links are correctly implemented, this isn't really an issue for them.

Comment: There isn't any sensitive data in the request ... the only thing I'm sending along is within the URL and it's just a param that indicates what product they're purchasing.

Comment: @dcolumbus, whether there's sensitive data in the request doesn't really matter. The point is that there shouldn't be any request to that URL that's not over HTTPS (if you always want it over HTTPS), so anything that sends a plain request first will be a mistake. Forcing it to break helps you detect that mistake and prevent wrong assumptions (perhaps one day you'll start putting sensitive data in the request by mistake too).

Comment: All I want to do is make sure that when a user is directed to `/cart/`, we force the SSL on. Just so there's no way they could go through the process without the SSL.

Comment: @dcolumbus Exactly my point: return 404s on `/cart/` on your main site, or redirect them to your main page (probably better). This will force you to make sure that everything that redirects to `/cart/` uses an `https://` address, which is the right way to do. Rewrites will just hides potential mistakes during the development process. Don't leave those mistakes in dev or in prod.

Comment: I SEE! Just needed that extra explanation... that actually makes a lot of sense. So do you suggest that be done with .htaccess? If so, what would you recommend as the rules?

Comment: @dcolumbus, not sure, but I guess a straight `RewriteRule ^cart/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/` (redirecting to the root of your site) should be enough to break the process, while at the same time making it better than 404s for users who'd feel like tweaking the address bar by hand. If you really want to redirect to an HTTPS URL, make sure it's always to a page that can't do any useful processing (i.e. no `$1`).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this *before* the other rules (but after RewriteBase):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^cart/(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/cart/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Is there something that is redirecting https back to http? What does your logs say?

Comment: /home/108777/domains/mydomain.com/html/.htaccess: Redirect to non-URL