# force https to a certain url

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I know this issue has been addressed in many ways, but couldn't find any similar to this one I have now. The thing is that I have a code to force `https` to a certain or a particular url, but it seems that the (s) letter can be removed by hand so the url goes with http instead!! I mean I want the https to be force again in case the url is changed from https to http.

I hope it is a clear explanation.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} main
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/login$1 [R,L]
```

does this code redirect again in case https is changed??

Thanks

**Update #1**
I got the meaning of what I want to point out to. It is called "blocked crawling of https"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force HTTPS for specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105510/force-https-for-specific-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} main
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/login$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ThinkingMonkey. however, quick question, if I change the https to http by hand, would it go back to https?? I will try it now and see how things go

Comment: I tried it, but it seems there is something wrong... I believe it is the "main" directory.

Comment: @Digitalsite `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} main` was in your above code(in question). So assumed that You want to redirect a page that has '_main_' in it's URI. Ya it will redirect to https even if https is changed to http by hand.

Comment: @Digitalsite which is(are) the URL(s) you want to redirect to https even if https is changed to http by hand.

Comment: ok, I see now. however, I tried, but still it doesn't redirect if I changed it to http... any idea why? and the url I want to be always https is the one for the login since it is the most important one.

Comment: @Digitalsite put this code at the very top after `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteBase /`. And also clear the browser cache. Before accessing the page. It should definitely work.