# Free Shared SSL Certificate redirect using .htaccess to Parked Domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, ssl-certificate, subdomain

Hi i use go location on my site and notice the warning message:

getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

with jushost you get a free shared ssl certificate:
https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/126

so i set this up my link is something like
https://justxxx.justhost.com/~justxxx/office/index.php. this is a parked domain. the question when the user enters http//office.xxxx/index.php  i would like show
https//office.xxxx/index.php  in the address put redirect to https://justxxx.justhost.com/~justxxx/office/index.php. Not sure how to go about this. I think it can be done in the .htaccess file but i am a little lost.
Any help would be great
Thanks
Jon

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you. Read the comments in it. I can't totally understand what you are trying to do but if you are trying to redirect http to https this will work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Edit1:
If you just want to redirect that specific url. See this question: [.htaccess https redirect for a single page (using relative urls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899258/htaccess-https-redirect-for-a-single-page-using-relative-urls)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer the issue is i do not want to purchase ssl certificate just for one page the as getCurrentPosition()  so i used the free ssl certificate which the link is  https://justxxx.justhost.com/~justxxx/office/index.php. to get to the page but  the user will enter http//office.xxx.co.uk and i need this to redirect to  https://justxxx.justhost.com/~justxxx/office/index.php but show https//office.xxx.co.uk/index.php  in the address bar ?

Comment: If all you are trying to do is make a redirect you can use a client seed redirect in PHP for example: http://www.somacon.com/p536.php This might help?